# check email DNS is valid or not

Tags: php

I am searching a lot, but didn't get proper answer of it so finally posted this question here.
I want to check that my given Email address with the domain name is valid or not(Domain exists or not).

Read this example,
I have 5 corresponding emails said: `keyur5390@gmail.com, demo@vishal.com, test@hotmail.com, test@yahoo.com, test@mitesh.com`

Here for all of these 5 email, `gmail.com, hotmail.com, yahoo.com` are valid websites and have a valid mail address, but `vishal.com` and mitesh.com` like websites are not live or not running, So i want to check those type of domain which are really working and fetch email id of those domain only.

I don't want demo@vishal.com, test@mitesh.com like emails, just because they are invalid domains.

So if there is any way let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: You are going to need a regular expression that has all possible valid domain names in it (basically it's going to be very very long and possibly will not include everything). Or you could use a simple `regexp` and check by sending a confirmation email.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check for DNS like this

```
var_dump(checkdnsrr("ofcoursethisis232342343243fakedomain.com"));
```

Please note this will still not check whether the email account itself exists. It will only check if domain has a valid dns record, as your question implies.

[Reference](https://www.php.net/checkdnsrr)

Comment: Hello, it will always return `true` (in all case.. even live domain or not.) So this will not work as I want to check.

Comment: That is wrong assumption. Why will it return true even if the domain doesn't exist? It will return false if the provided domain name doesn't have a dns record. I use it all the time and it works like you want it to. Give it a dummy domain name which you know is fake, then see. Even my example returns false.

Comment: I use this but it will return true only. Even your given example line is not working. It also return true

Comment: Actually copy pasting doesn't always go very well when programming. You aren't willing to take a suggestion and try it, and rather wish to just copy and paste. Ironically testing12345.com does exist (for sale for 1495) that is why it returns true. Try the domain I just put up and see the answer.

Comment: Also you can add a second parameter to `checkdnsrr`, which checks only the MX record of that domain. Such as `checkdnsrr( "makeupafkedomain.co.uk", true)`

Comment: Thanks @DebreczeniAndrás, `MX` is already the default value for the second parameter for this function.

Comment: In fact there are many functions here which can be used for this purpose http://us1.php.net/manual/en/ref.network.php

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky let me clear one thing, `vishal.com`
I also try with this one, this is not site, this is fake doamin, still it will return true to me. 
And I already tried most of the things to do so, but not getting proper result.

Comment: Go here: http://whois.domaintools.com/vishal.com and see if vishal.com exists or not :) This website has existed for past 9 years at the very least. Whether it loads or not is another story, the dns record exists and it is a registered domain.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: OK. Assume you are right. But I dont think that you read full question. I want to check that URL is live or not.
And vishal.com is not live website. Just go to your browser and write on vishal.com, press enter and check it. It will not live website. Website is not there. So please Its my huble request that read question again

Comment: Your question asks to check if a *domain name is valid*. Checking for dns entry is the way to check if a domain is valid. Moreover domain validity can also mean if it ***syntactically*** conforms to the domain name standards. Clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry, with all due respect, I do not have more time to waste on this pretty simple stuff. Your other check can be as simple as `echo file_get_contents("http://www.vishal.com");`. If you wish, I can delete this answer.